# in jupyter/colab how can I get the code of a linux command?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm using colab and there is a mount point that I untar a file from but sometimes it returns an error. After a few minutes it always works so I'd like to retry until it works but I am not sure how to get the error code:

```
!tar -xzvf $filename

Not downloading data
tar (child): ./companyJSON/filePath.tar.gz: Cannot open: Input/output error
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Ideally I want to get an error and process it like:

```
def untarrerFunc(filename):
   !tar -xzvf $filename
   if ErrorCode != 0:
       untarrerFunc(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try following:

```
from IPython import get_ipython

exit_code = get_ipython().__dict__['user_ns']['_exit_code']
```

Variable `exit_code` should contain exit code of the last call.